# Window not appearing when using pyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to perform a GUI with python using PyQt5.

When i run the below code, no error returned but also no Window appreared:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Page(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)

        my_label = QLabel("This is my label")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(my_label)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(layout, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("My First Qt App")

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            import sys

            app = QApplication(sys.argv)

            window = Page()
            window.show()

            sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct your indent if **main** should be out of class

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Page(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)

        my_label = QLabel("This is my label")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(my_label)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(layout, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("My First Qt App")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Page()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's working now, i didn't notice that :-) . thanks for helping.